# Cannot pip install watson-developer-cloud

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson

OS: Windows 10 x64

I am trying to install watson-developer-cloud using the command

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

However, I get the following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", 
line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Users\AurangzebRathore\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 97, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\AurangzebRathore\\Anaconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\_cffi_backend.pyd'
```

I tried to use

```
$ easy_install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

but when I run the code, it still says

```
ImportError: No module named watson_developer_cloud
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running command as *administrator*.

- Find the Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
- Right click on "Command Prompt"
- Run as Administrator

After it, use `pip --version` and see if are working. If not, you need to install again. If you installed Python from source, with an installer from python.org, or via Homebrew you should already have `pip`.

If `pip` isn’t already installed, then first try to bootstrap it from the standard library:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

And try update your pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade
```

Install your Watson package:

```
pip install -I watson-developer-cloud==0.26.1
```

Obs.: This is the Official command in the API Reference, as you can see in this [link](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?python#).

- See more about in this useful [Installing Packages - Python](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id12).

Comment: I tried all of these before hand and it didn't work. And yes, I have been running cmd as an administrator to do so. I ended up working on Java, installing the Watson package using Jar files. But this is really bothering me. Could it be a problem with my Python Environment? (The machine is new.)

Comment: yeah, probably, try to create one environment variable for use Python. Every time that I installed Python in some computer, I needed to create one environment variable, I don't know why but Windows always requested.